# Best method for appending new column in tab delimited csv file

Tags: python

How can I read and write at the same time in csv file.

```
def read_txt_file(txt_filename):

def get_all_sheet_values(filename):
    lines = []
    myFile= open( filename, "rU" )
    for aRow in myFile:
        val =  aRow.split('\t')
        val = map(lambda s: s.strip(), val)
        if len(val) > 1 :
            print val
            lines.append(val)
    myFile.close()
    return lines

files_dict = get_all_sheet_values(txt_filename)
return files_dict
```

So basically this code works file.

my problem is writing to the same csv file.
example,

```
10 10 10 10 10 \n
11 11 11 11 11  \n
22 22 22 22 22  \n
```

so after iterating each row I have to add status to it.

```
10 10 10 10 10 correct time1 \n
11 11 11 11 11 wrong   time2  \n
22 22 22 22 22 correct time3  \n
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Files don't work that way. Write to a new file, and rename it after.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. When you add the column you are making each line longer. If you were to write it out before going to the next line you would overwrite a portion of it.