# What is the logic to go through a text file with python and manipulate the file

Tags: scripting, logic

I have a text file with two columns, one is a Postcode and the other is a cross-reference ID. 
See example of file below

```
"AB564SH","VAB00824"
"AB564RL","VAB00824"
"AB564SY","VAB00825"
"AB564RQ","VAB00825"
"AB564SH","VAB00826"
"AB564RR","VAB00826"
```

What I want to do is if the value in the 2nd column (the v value), is the same as the previous column, then append the Postcode to the to the line, into a third column separated with a "/", so in essence the example above should end up like this

```
"AB564SH","VAB00824","/AB564SH/"
"AB564RL","VAB00824","/AB564SH/AB564RL/"
"AB564SY","VAB00825","/AB564SY/"
"AB564RQ","VAB00825","/AB564SY"AB564RQ/"
"AB564SH","VAB00826","/AB564SH"
"AB564RR","VAB00826","/AB564SH/AB564RR/"
```

Am I right in saying that to do this for each line, I need to

1. Create 3 empty lists, each to hold each column
2. Add the value to the list
3. Use an if statement to check whether the V value is teh same as the Previous V value if yes then add the postcode to the 3rd list
4. Then append the 3rd column to the end of each line

Am I on the right track or am i not making sense?

Comment: Don't you think this question would be more appropriate on SO?  It doesn't need any GIS expertise to understand or answer.

Comment: Or even an Excel forum..! Try "=if(cell=cell_above),concatenate..."

Comment: Get rid of the arcgis tab please, as this has absolutely nothing to do with arcgis and I am also unsure the python tag should be here too, as this is a simple scripting issue, and nothing to do with gis, python or anything; its s simple logic issue...  Also, not being nasty, or anything, but is IT the field for you if you need to ask about things like this?

Answer (score 0):

Step 4 [makes no sense](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5658466/20862).  And you don't need a list; just process the file a single line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bit complicated, I would work on a row by row bases.

1. Read the row, remember the two values
2. ***If*** the second value is the same than in the previous line append the previous and the current value to the current line ***else*** append only the current value
3. Write the resulting line into a new file
4. Repeat for all lines.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you only need to store the last value of the second column, and the string (or list) of the values concatenated so far. For each row, if the value of the second column is the same as the stored one, then concatenate a new string to the list and print it in the third column. Otherwise, empty the list, add the left value and print it. In both cases, update the stored value of the last 2nd column value read.

This should do it, assuming that I understood the question correctly.